# jquery blur not working/triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know much about jquery and javascript. This is my code for input text where i want to use blur to validate the field

```
  <div class="form-row form-input-name-row" >

                <label>
                    <span>Full name</span>
                    <input id="txt_name" type="text" name="name">
                </label>

                <!--
                    Add these three elements to every form row. They will be shown by the
                    .form-valid-data and .form-invalid-data classes (see the JS for an example).
                -->

                <span class="form-valid-data-sign"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>

                <span class="form-invalid-data-sign"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></span>
                <span class="form-invalid-data-info"></span>

            </div>
```

this is my javascript code where i have added the blur function

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Here is how to show an error message next to a form field
 $("#txt_name").blur(function() {

        var errorField = $('.form-input-name-row');

        // Adding the form-invalid-data class will show
        // the error message and the red x for that field

        errorField.addClass('form-invalid-data');
        errorField.find('.form-invalid-data-info').text('Please enter your name');

});​
        // Here is how to mark a field with a green check mark

        var successField = $('.form-input-email-row');

        successField.addClass('form-valid-data');



    });
     $(".clicker").click(function(){
    $(".file").click();
});



function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}



</script>
```

I am also using bootstrap, can somebody tell why blur is not firing?

Comment: you imported the JQuery library right?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> under head

Comment: `});​
        // Here is how to mark a field with a green check mark`
Here, after *;* I got illegal character.  Do you copy it from source code?

Comment: yes @MedetAhmetsonAtabayev

Comment: Try to delete and put again those *;* from example. Do you find illegal character?

Comment: Yes it was not showing in intellij but when i posted in jsfiddle, it was there. thanks . Now it works. @MedetAhmetsonAtabayev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/ra3bbtow/

```
});​ // Here is how to mark a field with a green check mark
```

There is a red dot, that's a character which was not showing in my ide. Thanks to
@MedetAhmetsonAtabayev

Answer (score 0):

The `blur` event is being fired. Here is your code with `alert()` in the blur callback.

PS. Just a quick note. `blur` is fired when you `focus` and then "focus-out".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Here is how to show an error message next to a form field
  $("#txt_name").blur(function() {
    
    alert('Blur event fired!');                        // < === HERE ===

    var errorField = $('.form-input-name-row');

    // Adding the form-invalid-data class will show
    // the error message and the red x for that field

    errorField.addClass('form-invalid-data');
    errorField.find('.form-invalid-data-info').text('Please enter your name');

  });
  // Here is how to mark a field with a green check mark

  var successField = $('.form-input-email-row');

  successField.addClass('form-valid-data');
});

$(".clicker").click(function() {
  $(".file").click();
});

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-row form-input-name-row">

  <label>
    <span>Full name</span>
    <input id="txt_name" type="text" name="name">
  </label>

  <!--
    Add these three elements to every form row. They will be shown by the
    .form-valid-data and .form-invalid-data classes (see the JS for an example).
  -->

  <span class="form-valid-data-sign"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
  <span class="form-invalid-data-sign"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></span>
  <span class="form-invalid-data-info"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: You are not doing anything wrote. The `blur` event is being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
 errorField.addClass('form-invalid-data');
        errorField.find('.form-invalid-data-info').text('Please enter your name');

});​
```

Try with this code,hope it will work ,ommiting semicolon ";"

```
 errorField.addClass('form-invalid-data');
        errorField.find('.form-invalid-data-info').text('Please enter your name');

})
```